# How do I make dialogue only appear once?

Tags: unity, c#

So I made it so when I walk over a NPC it brings up 12 lines of dialogue, and you press E to get to the next line. When the dialogue is over you can keep pressing E and it will bring the dialogue up every time. I want it so it only brings the dialogue up once. How do I do that?

This is my script for it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class dialogHolder : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string dialogue;
    private DialogueManager dMan;

    public string[] dialogueLines;

    public float questComplete;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() 
    {
        dMan = FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Shrump")
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
            {
                //dMan.ShowBox(dialogue);
                if (!dMan.dialogActive)
                {
                    dMan.dialogLines = dialogueLines;
                    dMan.currentLine = 0;
                    dMan.ShowDialogue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to record whether or not this npc has already been talked to. The way to store that will vary depending on your code architecture, but the simplest way is to simply add a boolean talkedTo that starts false and turns true when dialogue starts, and add !talkedTo in the if condition.

Comment: As a minor code review comment, I suggest naming the boolean `showDialogue` instead of `wasTalkedTo`. You don't want to use the _reason_ (already having talked to the person), because there may be multiple reasons why you don't want dialogue to be shown (e.g. already talked to NPC, NPC is in combat, NPC is dead, you don't have the needed quest, ...) and then you can't provide a single reason for the name anymore.

Comment: I would argue that there should be a showDialogue bool *in addition to* not *instead of* wasTalkedTo, but it mostly boils down to what behavior exactly is desired. wasTalkedTo is a permanent value that is set when you talk to them and never changes again, while showDialogue turns on and off depending on the situation. showDialogue could even be a property derived from a bunch of other properties, including wasTalkedTo: public bool showDialogue { get { return isAlive && !wasTalkedTo && etc; } }

Comment: That gets pretty close to business logic via naming; which is imo overengineering. If you need a local variable to determine if a conversation has been completed, by all means create a local variable. But storing two boolean class properties that map one to one for a functionality that currently only requires one switch is overengineering, in my opinion.

Comment: No I'm not talking about a local variable, I'm talking about persistent values that mean different things. Like, you gave the example of an NPC that can't talk because they are in combat; their ability to engage in dialogue would turn back on after combat, but whether or not they've already been talked to would not change. A singular showDialogue for everything wouldn't be able to distinguish those situations.

Comment: `class properties that map one to one for a functionality that currently only requires one switch is overengineering` I would agree, that would be overengineering, but that's not what's happening here. The values aren't directly mapping, they interact in non-trivial ways. Consider this example: an NPC that's never been talked to is in combat, so you cannot talk right away but can after combat is over. Another NPC has been talked to already, so you can't talk to them both during and after combat.

Answer (score 0):

If this file contains code only to handle the dialog, simply `Destroy` it after displaying the dialog.

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Shrump")
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (!dMan.dialogActive)
            {
                dMan.dialogLines = dialogueLines;
                dMan.currentLine = 0;
                dMan.ShowDialogue();

                // Destroy this file
                Destroy(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I don't know how `dMan` works and I assume when you call `ShowDialoge()` it can handle the rest without caring about the script that called it.

Answer (score -1):

Use a boolean at the beginning.

```
hasTalked = false;


if(hasTalked == false)
     {

     //(The rest of your code)


     //end it by turning the boolean to true

     hasTalked = true;
     } else
{
break;
}
```

At the end of the function, we will change hasTalked to true, and then when the function checks and sees that hasTalked == true, it will skip the dialog and not display anything.  Maybe you could make it say "..." or something.

Have fun!